# When / how is a contact created when sending out a test newsletter

Tags: civimail, duplicate-contacts, mosaico

Recently we stumbled upon duplicate contacts in our system, who had merely an email-address.

After some digging it seems that they were created when users utilize Mosaico to design an email and then send a test version to themselves. My understanding of this feature is as follows:

If a user sends a test email from mosaico (not sure if it applies to regular CiviMail as well) and enters a test recipients email address which is not in CiviCRM yet, a contact is created who has merely that email-address.

However, in our case it seems as if an additional contact is created althoug the contact is already in the system.

Hence my questions:

Does anyone know if the feature really works as described?

And if this is the case is one of the individual matching rules (e.g. the unsupervised one) applied? That would explain the duplicates.